# aplicação real time com php

Tags: php, iis, websocket, ssl, node.js

Eu tem o seguinte problema preciso implementar ações em real time em uma aplicação já desenvolvida usando php rodando no iis.

Eu já consegui fazer minha aplicação comunicar com uma aplicação em node.js(que poderia ser react php, inclusive fiz uma versão assim) e enviar mensagem para o cliente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso já seria suficiente para atender a minha necessidade se não fosse por um detalhe o site e carregado por https e aplicação node.js escuta na porta 9000 sem https, ai o navegar bloqueia o conteúdo.

Eu gostaria de saber se tem como habilitar a ssl tanto na porta 443 quanto na porta 9000 com o mesmo certificado digital?

Se alguém conhecer alguma solução diferente para meu problema por favor deixar registrada.

Comment: Eu tive esse problema. A solução dada pelo pessoal do servidor foi criar abrir a porta 9001, com SSL, que "redirecionava" para a porta 9000. O meu plano é o semi-dedicado da Dialhost

Comment: Como foi feito isso?
Tenho pouco conhecimento quando se fala de infra ou rede. e vou ser eu que terei que habilitar o ssl, então se você puder dar mais algum detalhe seria muito.